# Возможно ли в node js puppeteer работать с новыми окнами браузера?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

работаю с сайтом, который использует расширение, открывающее именно новое окно браузера, не в соседней вкладке а отдельным окном. Умеет ли puppeteer как-нибудь обрабатывать такие открытия и взаимодействовать с ними как с обычными объектом драйвера?

Comment: умеет https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/#event-targetcreated

Comment: хороший пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/66573572/4496422